# TuxGuitar 1.4 Cannot Edit Volume

Tags: guitar, tablature, mac, tuxguitar

I know there were other posts about this but in my case selecting "V" will not let me edit the volume or anything at all in the new mixer. All of the faders are stationary. I can do 127, 27, and 0 but cannot slide them anywhere between. I tried downloading an older version 1.2 and had the same issue. I am running Sierra on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: It's not an answer, just wondering. Why are you using TuxGuitar? There are some other good tab editors like Guitar Pro, MuseScore, Sibelius, Dorico.